# How to use Custom Exception for Spring Boot Rest?

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, spring-boot

Am using Spring Boot to connect to MySQL 5 database (via JPA) along with Spring Rest for the server side.

My POJO:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

EmployeRespository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "employee", path = "employee")
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {

    Collection<Employee> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

EmployeeService:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findByLastName?{lastName}=", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Object getEmployees(@PathVariable String lastName) {
        Collection<Employee> result = this.employeeRepository.findByLastName(lastName);
        if (result == null) {
            throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(lastName);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

EmployeeNotFoundException:

```
public class EmployeeNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public EmployeeNotFoundException(String id) {
        super("Could not find Employee " + id);
    }
}
```

Now when call call my REST API, I get the following results:

This one doesn't exist in my database and the EmployeeNotFoundException is not thrown:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/employee/search/findByLastName?name="Smith"
```

Results in:

```
{
    "_embedded" : {
        "employee" : [ ]
    },
    "_links" : {
        "self" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employee/search/findByLastName?name=Smith"
        }
    }
}
```

Question(s):

1. Why is my EmployeeNotFoundException being thrown? Is there a better way to implement this (along with perhaps the HTTP Status Code being displayed)?
2. Any URL(s) regarding how to unit test would be great (along with the best unit test libraries)...

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 4):

It's because, following line does not return null, but an empty list.

```
Collection<Employee> result = this.employeeRepository.findByLastName(lastName);
```

You can either check for empty list as well for throwing Exception, or just return the empty list as well. I would not recommend throwing Exception for find/ search. I personally, throw any `NotFoundException` only for get methods like `getById`. Otherwise I just return the empty list.

```
if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {
    throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(lastName);
}
```

Also, modification to Hey-men-wattsup's code to send error code, instead of throwing exception in the Controller. This will send 404, NotFound code.

```
@ExceptionHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException.class)
    public void handleException(EmployeeNotFoundException  e, , HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), e.getMessage());
}
```

Spring Boot Test's MockMvc class combined with Mockito provides required methods to unit test a controller.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're wondering about that *`EmployeeNotFoundException`*, it's thrown  but not being handled.
You need at least one `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method to handle it.

```
 @ExceptionHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException.class)
        public void handleException(EmployeeNotFoundException  e) {
        // do something
        }
```

Like so :

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/employee")
    public class EmployeeService {

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/findByLastName?{lastName}=", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        Object getEmployees(@PathVariable String lastName) {
            Collection<Employee> result = this.employeeRepository.findByLastName(lastName);
            if (result == null) {
                throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(lastName);
            }
            return result;
        }

       @ExceptionHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException.class)
        public void handleException(EmployeeNotFoundException  e) {
         System.out.println("Exception triggered");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion is still not working... I don't see "Exception triggered" anywhere on stdout.